# SELECT statement around the result of an INNER JOIN statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I'm using MySQL database version 5.6.17
and I have the following tables

1. users

   - ID
   - username
2. series

   - imdbID
3. episode

   - imdbID
   - season
   - episode
   - imdbVotes
   - seriesID
   - type
4. marktype

   - ID
   - type
5. test aka(serieswatchlist)

   - ID
   - userid
   - epid
   - markid

**PLEASE NOTE:** not I removed most of the columns in each table to reduce the question length
I managed to extract the following data (all users data, all episode data, all series data) using the following SQL code

```
SELECT e.*, u.username, s.*
FROM test w
INNER JOIN users u
ON u.ID = w.userid
INNER JOIN episode e
ON w.epid = e.imdbID
INNER JOIN series s
ON e.seriesID = s.imdbID
WHERE e.seriesID IN (SELECT (imdbID) FROM series) 
AND w.userid = 1
```

but I want to do another operation on the result of that SQL statement
I want to get from each series it's max season number and the max episode number that belong to that season from that series using SQL statement as well.
so far each time I try to write any code before the previous code it always give me an error no explanation except syntax error.

**UPDATE 1:**
tried the GROUP BY around the my code but it resulted in an error
"Every derived table must have its own alias"
here is the modified code

```
SELECT MAX(e.season) FROM
(SELECT e.seriesID, u.username, e.imdbID AS "episodeID"
FROM test w
INNER JOIN users u
ON u.ID = w.userid
INNER JOIN episode e
ON w.epid = e.imdbID
INNER JOIN series s
ON e.seriesID = s.imdbID
WHERE e.seriesID IN (SELECT (imdbID) FROM series) 
AND w.userid = 1)
GROUP BY seriesID
```

**UPDATE 2:**
changed the code to fix the error to the following

```
SELECT MAX(x.season), max(x.episode) FROM
(SELECT e.seriesID, u.username, e.imdbID AS "episodeID", e.season, e.episode
FROM test w
INNER JOIN users u
ON u.ID = w.userid
INNER JOIN episode e
ON w.epid = e.imdbID
INNER JOIN series s
ON e.seriesID = s.imdbID
WHERE e.seriesID IN (SELECT (imdbID) FROM series) 
AND w.userid = 1) as x
GROUP BY x.seriesID
```

it's working without any problems

Comment: Actors? What? How does that work?

Comment: Minimize the problem. For example there are so many columns of no importance that can be removed from question.

Comment: @Strawberry still working on the functionality of that one but in it's value are text for example (john doe, my x, miss y)

Comment: @jarlh I can control what I want to extract from the SQL statement but that's no problem, I just want to know how will i do a select statement on the result of that SQL statement

Comment: @hamada147: what jarlh meant was, please remove the irrelevant columns (and tables) from your **question**. Reduce the question to the smallest number of tables and columns that still reproduce your problem.

Comment: Place the existing query in a FROM section (as a subquery) and apply necessary GROUP BY and aggregate functions

Comment: @Martha go it, will edit it right now

Comment: @StanislavL will try it now

Comment: @StanislavL Tried it but I'm doing something wrong, it's telling me "Every derived table must have its own alias " will update the question

Comment: it should be **select... from (the subuery) <alias_name> group by <alias_name>.some_field** e.g. alias name could be **sub**

Comment: @StanislavL it's working without any problems ^_^ please reply with it as an answer so I can mark as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the existing query in a `FROM` section (as a subquery) and apply necessary `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions

it should be

```
select ... 
from (the subuery) <alias_name> 
group by <alias_name>.some_field
```

e.g. alias name could be `sub`